# Pop up on page load only to load once per user

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have set up a overlay background on page load, however i only need it to load once per user so that if click off the page and come back you dont see the overlay again. any help with this would be highly appreciated. Here's my code:

```
<div class="overlay-bg">

    <div class="overlay-inner">
        <h2>To explore more simply...</h2>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <p>Drag</p>
        <img src="AW16/pages/AW16_Lookbook_Timeoutmessage_03_02_new.gif?$staticlink$" alt="Hit List" height="85" width="80">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 middle-col">
        <p>or</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <p>Use arrow</p>
        <img src="AW16/pages/AW16_Lookbook_Timeoutmessage_05_02_new.gif?$staticlink$" alt="Hit List" height="85" width="123">
    </div>
    <a class="close-btn-new">CLOSE</a>

</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

// function to show our popups
function showPopup(whichpopup){
 if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)doSomethingOnlyOnce\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") !== "true") {
$('.overlay-bg').show(); //display your popup background and set     height  to   the page height
document.cookie = "doSomethingOnlyOnce=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";
}
}

// function to close our popups
function closePopup(){
$('.overlay-bg').hide(); //hide the overlay
}


// hide popup when user clicks on close button or if user clicks     anywhere outside the container
$('.close-btn-new, .overlay-bg').click(function(){
closePopup();
});


});
</script>
```

Comment: You want to show popup only once for each user session?

Comment: I mean each time you refresh browser, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By clicking off the page, I am assuming you mean after refreshing the page you don't want it to show again.  To do this, you are going to need to track user state across pages refreshes.  You'll either need to store the information that a user has seen the page in a database or in something like a cookie that is persistent when the page refreshes.

You can find the code to set the site to do something only once on the Mozilla MDN site:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

```
code from mozilla site: 

function doOnce() {
  if (document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)doSomethingOnlyOnce\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1") !== "true") {
    alert("Do something here!");
    document.cookie = "doSomethingOnlyOnce=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";
  }
}
```

EDIT: 
I created a gist with a working example. 
https://gist.github.com/kemiller2002/658e69a899e874e01026ba05f83f7454

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Kev. I am struggling to implement this into my scenario. please see edited question above

Comment: so, looking at the code you posted, I don't think you're calling showPopup anywhere.  Also, if you are using Chrome to develop, and you are developing a local page (not going through a webserver), Chrome will ignore the local cookie.  Try switching to FireFox and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: what should go in place of 'doSomethingOnlyOnce'?

Comment: I'm away from my computer at the moment, but when I get back I'll check it.  I don't ramen eve that needing to be changed though.  I'll double check

Comment: I created a gist with the code to show the popup working.  It has an else statement that will remove the cookie for testing.  To have it only show once instead of every other time, just remove the else statement in the showPopup function.  If it doesn't do what you expected let me know, and I'll keep looking at it.
https://gist.github.com/kemiller2002/658e69a899e874e01026ba05f83f7454

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

// function to show our popups
function showPopup(whichpopup){
    if (typeof(localStorage.popupDisplayCount) == "undefined") {
        localStorage.popupDisplayCount = 1;
        $('.overlay-bg').show(); //display your popup background and set     height to   the page height
    }
}

// function to close our popups
function closePopup(){
$('.overlay-bg').hide(); //hide the overlay
}


// hide popup when user clicks on close button or if user clicks     anywhere outside the container
$('.close-btn-new, .overlay-bg').click(function(){
closePopup();
});


});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, the above doesn't work for me, any other suggestions? thanks